# If $\arccos(x)+\arccos(y)+\arccos(z)=3\pi$, then prove that $xy+yz+zx=3$.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\arccos(x)+\arccos(y)+\arccos(z)=3\pi$, then prove that $(xy)+(yz)+(zx)=3$. I am trying this question for nearly $2$ months but I am unable to find an accurate solution to this question. I found this question from one of the sample question paper. First of all I am trying this question by breaking $3\pi$ as $\pi+\pi+\pi$. Now I am getting
$\arccos(x)+\arccos(y)+\arccos(z)=\pi+\pi+\pi$. Now I am equating $\arccos(x)=\pi$; $\arccos(y)=\pi$; $\arccos(z)=\pi$. So, I am getting $x=y=z=\cos(\pi)$. That is $x=y=z=-1$. So, therefore from this I can easily prove that $(xy)+(yz)+(zx)=3$. But still after solving this question I have one doubt. In that sample paper from where I found this question, in this question it was not mentioned that $x=y=z$. So, my doubt is that how to prove that $(xy)+(yz)+(zx)=3$ without taking $x=y=z$? By taking $x=y=z$; we can easily prove that $(xy)+(yz)+(zx)=3$. Please help me out.

Comment: $\operatorname{arccos}t\le \pi$ for all $t\in[-1,1]$, therefore the sum can be equal to $3\pi$ only if the three terms are all $\pi$. Therefore $x=y=z=-1$.

Comment: But can there be any alternate solution other than this@SassatelliGiulio? I have already mentioned your way of approach.

Comment: You have not done my approach. I suggest you think about the difference between what I've said and what you've said.

Comment: You see the function arccos(x)+arccos(y)+arccos(z)=3π is a decreasing function. As each term is individually a decreasing function. Such constantly increasing or decreasing function is the property of one to one function, i.e there only one input for one output. Thus, the above function can only have one solution for each of x, y, z which is -1, -1, -1 which we found from above. I hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

$\arccos(x)+\arccos(y)+\arccos(z)=3π$, as the range of $\arccos$ is $[0,π]$ so the value of $\arccos(x)=\arccos(y)=\arccos(z)=π$ is the only possible values. Then for $\arccos(x)= π , x=-1$. Similarly, $y=z=-1$ as well.

So, $xy+yz+zx= (-1)\cdot(-1)+(-1)\cdot(-1)+(-1)\cdot(-1) = 1+1+1 =3$.

Hence proved.

P.S: I'm sorry, it seems like I didn't read the body part of your query and answered hapazardly. Now answering your actual query:

You see the function arccos(x)+arccos(y)+arccos(z)=3π is a decreasing functions. As each term is individually a decreasing function. Such constantly increasing or decreasing function is the property of one to one function, i.e there only one input for one output. Thus, the above function can only have one solution for each of x, y, z which is -1, -1, -1 which we found from above 'trick'. I hope this answered your actual question. Sorry for the blunder.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$\arccos x + \arccos y = \begin{cases}\arccos(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}), \qquad x+y \ge 0,\\
2\pi - \arccos(xy-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}), \quad x+y < 0.\end{cases}$

Comment: Ok. Thank you everyone for helping me out with this question.

Comment: You're welcome @ShivamKumar and thanks for recommendation!